# ASP.NET Slow email sending

Tags: asp.net, email

In my web app (ASP.NET MVC), I send an email using the following:

```
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage("email@domain.com", "somewhere@recipient");
        msg.Body = "Message body";
        msg.IsBodyHtml = false;
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        msg.Subject = "Subject";
        client.Send(msg);
```

My system.net Mail Settings are as follows in web.config:

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="email@domain.com">
        <network host="mail.domain.com" port="25" defaultCredentials="false" userName="email@domain.com" password="mypassword" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

This sends out the email fine. The only issue I've experienced is that the email is sent and received within 2-3 minutes of the function call.

I've seen this on two hosts that use SmarterMail, and before I ask the good folks at serverfault.com and then question my host, I wanted to know if theres anything coding-wise that could be causing this 2-3 minute delay.

It may seem negligible, but I as a web surfer, hate it when emails that I'm supposed to get take long, specially if they have crucial information like login information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think this is about your servers network traffic.

Answer (score 1):

There are two simple ways to test if the delivery delay is caused by your program or not:

1. Send a mail by some other means, e.g., by starting a mail client or using some [command-line mail client](http://sourceforge.net/projects/blat/) (using the same SMTP server). If the mail shows the same delay, your software has nothing to do with it.
2. Alternatively, you could look into the *headers* of one of the received mails: They should show now much time the mail spends on every mail server along the route. If you have trouble interpreting the headers, add them to your question or [have a look at one of the tutorials online](http://www.google.com/search?q=read+email+headers).

(BTW, I share Ozan's assumption that the delay is caused by the mail server rather than by your program.)