# eMail from asp.net c# program very slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am sending a simple email message from an asp.net web page to two recipients. It's taking about 15 seconds to finish execution. Is it possible to speed this up? This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace NihulKriotNS.BLL
{
public class EMailClass
{
    //fields
    private const string strFrom = "myEmail";
    private const string mailServer = "myServer";
    private const string userName = "myUserName";
    private const string usePass = "myPassword";
    //ctors
    public EMailClass()
    {
    }

    public void SendEMail(List<string> emailList, string strSubject, string  strMessage, bool isHTML)
              {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.From = new MailAddress(strFrom);
        if (emailList != null && emailList.Count > 0 )
            foreach (string em in emailList)
            {
                msg.To.Add(em);
            }
        else
            return;
        msg.Subject = strSubject;
        msg.Body = strMessage;
        msg.IsBodyHtml = isHTML;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(mailServer);
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, usePass);


        smtp.Send(msg);
        msg.Dispose();
    }
}
```

}

I tried using smpt.SendAsync but didn't help at all. I'm not realy sure how to use it properly.
Thank you very much.

Comment: I am assuming that it is something with the network call to the smtp server. Are you using a hostname that take a while to look up? What happens if you use an IP address?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Slow email sending](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945111/asp-net-slow-email-sending)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earlier I received an answer from Samir Adel (and confirmed in a comment by someone else I don't remember who) to use multiple threads. For some reason, unfortunately, this answer has deleted. I wasn't familiar with the subject of threading. I looked up the subject in the book Pro C# 2008 and the .NET 3.5 Platform by Andrew Troelsen. I came up with the following code:

```
Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(EMailPrepareAndSend));
backgroundThread.Name = "Secondary";
backgroundThread.Start();
```

Where EMailPrepareAndSend is a method where the email message is prepared and from which the SendEmail() method in the EMail class, shown in my question, is called. This has enabled the program to continue immediately even tho the email has not finished being sent. Thank you to Samir Adel, his response got me in the right direction.

Comment: You are welcome Dov Miller, I m also surprised why my answer was deleted but I m so happy that my answer helped you solving your problem.

Comment: someone named Robert Harvey deleted my answer without even specifying why ?!

Comment: I'm not familliar with builtin Async methods, if you could give me an example I would be happy to use it. Thank you.

Comment: @Samir_Adel: Robert Harvey is one of the moderators.  If he deleted your answer, it is probably because it was flagged by somebody as either low quality, or not an answer. I don't have sufficient rep to see your answer, so I can't suggest a reason but you could ask on meta if you want more details.  In general, answers that are hard to read/understand, or consist purely of links are most likely to get deleted.